# DragonFlyBSD and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, bsd

Has anybody tried to run DragonFlyBSD (32-bit) over VirtualBox on a Windows (64-bit) host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I run NetBSD (64-bit) virtualized using VirtualBox (running on 64-bit Windows 7), and I find it to be efficient and reliable.  The 32-bit edition of NetBSD worked fine too, but I only tried it once.

Since DragonFlyBSD is a fork of FreeBSD, when creating your Guest environment in VirtualBox you'll probably want to select the "FreeBSD" presets at the "OS Type" prompt since there isn't one for DragonFlyBSD specifically.

Also:  If there isn't a compelling reason to use the 32-bit edition, I recommend using the 64-bit edition since it will work at least a little bit more efficiently.

Comment: Hi! I followed your advice and installed the 64bit version of DragonFlyBSD using the "FreeBSD" presets. It seems to be working without any problems. Thank you!